# How to position element in a SWF file to adapt to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to mask the attachment red box part of the picture any screen resolution; Have any good Suggestions?
attach image:

[image]

[red box part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grrRS.jpg;);
code:

```
<div style="background-color: fff;height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0;position:relative;">
<div id="mask1" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0top:10px;"></div>
<embed id="swf" width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://zd.diyifanwen.com/Files/WordSwf/%E6%9D%A8.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<div id="mask2" style="background:blue;width:600px;height:100px;position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where to red box part ??

Answer (score 0):

may be work this solution

add one `container` & add `position` `relative`

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <embed id="swf" width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://zd.diyifanwen.com/Files/WordSwf/%E6%9D%A8.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <div id="mask2" style="background:blue;width:600px;height:100px;position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;"></div>
</div>
```